# What is a good name for an instance method that adds a linked-list node after the target?

Tags: objective-c, methods, naming-conventions, linked-list

I'm creating a doubly-linked list in Objective-C. I would like my node class to include an instance method that allows me to add another node after the target node, like so:

```
// start <-> nodeA <-> nodeB <-> nodeC <-> end

Node * newNode = [Node node];
[NodeB thisMethodNeedsAGoodName:newNode];

// start <-> nodeA <-> nodeB <-> newNode <-> nodeC <-> end
```

What would be a good name for this method? `insertAfter:` sounds wrong, since that implies that the *target* is being inserted, not the new node. `insertNode:` would be OK, except that I'd like to write another method to insert a node *before* the target node, and then I'd have to come up with a different name for *that* method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably call it `appendNode:`, which would allow you to do an "insert before" method called `prependNode:`.  Then you just need to make sure it's clear that:

```
[aNode appendNode:newNode];
```

Is equivalent to:

```
[[aNode nextNode] prependNode:newNode];
```

(And if this is just a regular doubly-linked list, I'd recommend checking out [CHDataStructures](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/chdatastructures).  Quinn Taylor has done an excellent job of building a comprehensive framework of common data structures in Cocoa.)

Comment: +1 I like `appendNode:` & `prependNode:`. Thanks for the note about CHDataStructures as well. I'll have to check that out!